# Can't add a resize handle for an svg element in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am trying to build a web-based paint application using Angular and I am still a bit new to web development.
My application uses svg elements to render geometric shapes such as circle, rectangles,..etc
but I can't add a resize functionality to my application, I want to the user to be able to resize any svg element at will.

Here's my code

circle.component.html

```
<svg>
    <circle *ngFor="let circle of circles; let i = index" 
    (focus)="selectObject(i)" 
    [attr.cx]="circle.x" 
    [attr.cy]="circle.y" 
    [attr.r]="circle.r" 
    [attr.fill]="circle.color" 
        stroke="black"
        strokeWidth="3"
        cdkDrag 
    >
</circle>
</svg>
```

circle.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: '[app-circle]',
  templateUrl: './circle.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./circle.component.css'] 
})
export class CircleComponent implements OnInit {

  isPressed = false;
  selectedID = 1;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  circles: Circle[] = [
    {id:0, x: 50, y: 50, r: 40, color: 'red'},
    {id:1, x: 100, y: 200, r: 50, color: 'green'},
    {id:2, x: 200, y: 300, r: 60, color: 'blue'} 
  ];

  selectObject(index: number){
    this.selectedID = index;
    console.log('select called with index ' + index);
  }

}
```

I know i can simply change the r value for the circle I want to resize easily but I don't know how to add handles to my svg element to indicate that this is possible like this:
[What I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E1Yp.png)

I have tried putting 4 div elements as a child element inside my circle element to style it into little resize handles, but it turns out I can't put divs inside svg.

I also tried putting basic circle svg elements inside my circle and then style it, but angular does not render them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the "resizes" I've see are components in the way

```
<div class="resizable" [class.select]="selected"  [ngStyle]="style" >
  <ng-content ></ng-content>
  <div class="cell-top" ></div>
  <div class="cell-border-top" ></div>
  <div class="cell-border-bottom" ></div>
  <div class="cell-border-left" ></div>
  <div class="cell-border-right" ></div>
  <div class="cell-top-right" ></div>
  <div class="cell-bottom-right" ></div>
  <div class="cell-top-left" ></div>
  <div class="cell-bottom-left"></div>
</div>
```

Then, in a mouseDown check the className of the element to

1. Define a type of Drag
2. Subscribe to mouseUp
3. Subscribe to MouseMove

When the mouseUp is executed, the subscription to mouseMove is ended, when the mouse is move you calculate the new position, width and height. This applied an style.

```
merge(
fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'mousedown'),
fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'touchstart').pipe(map((event:TouchEvent)=>({
  target:event.target,
  screenX:event.touches[0].screenX,
  screenY:event.touches[0].screenY
}))
))
  .pipe(
    filter((event: MouseEvent) => {
      if (!this.selected)
        return false;
      const classs = (event.target as any).className;
      if (classs && typeof classs === 'string') {
        const className = classs.split(' ');
        const inside:boolean=(className.indexOf('cell-top')>0)
        if (inside)
        {
          this.selected=true;
        }
        return inside || this.classNames.indexOf(classs) >= 0;
      }
      return false;
    })
  )
  .subscribe((event: MouseEvent) => {
    this.origin =  { x: event.screenX, y: event.screenY };

    const className = (event.target as any).className.split(' ');
    this.typeDrag =
      className.indexOf('cell-top') >= 0
        ? TypeDrag.Move
        : (this.classNames.indexOf(className[0]) as TypeDrag);

    this.incr =
      this.typeDrag == TypeDrag.Move
        ? [1, 0, 1, 0]
        : this.typeDrag == TypeDrag.Top
        ? [1, -1, 0, 0]
        : this.typeDrag == TypeDrag.Bottom
        ? [0, 1, 0, 0]
        : this.typeDrag == TypeDrag.Right
        ? [0, 0, 0, 1]
        : this.typeDrag == TypeDrag.Left
        ? [0, 0, 1, -1]
        : this.typeDrag == TypeDrag.TopRight
        ? [1, -1, 0, 1]
        : this.typeDrag == TypeDrag.TopLeft
        ? [1, -1, 1, -1]
        : this.typeDrag == TypeDrag.BottomRight
        ? [0, 1, 0, 1]
        : [0, 1, 1, -1];


    merge(fromEvent(document, 'mouseup'),
          fromEvent(document,'touchend')
    )
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(() => {
        if (this.moveSubscription) {
          this.moveSubscription.unsubscribe();
          this.moveSubscription = undefined;
            this.rectInit={...this.rect}
          }
      });

    if (!this.moveSubscription) {
      this.moveSubscription = merge(
        fromEvent(document, 'mousemove'),
        fromEvent(document, 'touchmove').pipe(map((event:TouchEvent)=>({
          target:event.target,
          screenX:event.touches[0].screenX,
          screenY:event.touches[0].screenY
        }))
        ))
        .pipe(startWith({ screenY: this.origin.y, screenX: this.origin.x }))
        .subscribe((moveEvent: MouseEvent) => {
          const incrTop = moveEvent.screenY - this.origin.y;
          const incrLeft = moveEvent.screenX - this.origin.x;
          const width=this.rectInit.width + this.incr[3] * incrLeft;
          const height=this.rectInit.height + this.incr[1] * incrTop;
        this.rect={
            width:width<15?15:width,
            height:height<15?15:height,
            left:this.rectInit.left+this.incr[2] * incrLeft,
            top:this.rectInit.top+this.incr[0] * incrTop
          }
          this.style = {
            width: this.rect.width + 'px',
            height: this.rect.height + 'px',
            left:this.rect.left+ 'px',
            top:this.rect.top+ 'px'
          };

        });
    }
  });
```

I wrote this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahhden-zwygmb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fresize-border%2Fresize-border.component.ts). I hope can give you a clue or a point to starting